# Elegant/efficient way to create a class specific to another class from another class

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a class called `ToolConfigurationVector` and a class called `JointVariableVector`.
I need to be able to convert between those two classes (they are different representations of the same data)

A `ToolConfigurationVector` consists only of 6 primitive Datatypes. This is always the case.

A `JointVariableVector` is a representation that is specific to a Robotarm, represented by the **class** `Arm`.

So for one **subclass** of `Arm` (say `SimpleArm`) the representation and thus the conversion to `ToolConfigurationVector`  is completely different to representation and conversion of another **subclass** of `Arm` (say `ComplexArm`)

Later, I want to use those classes like this:

```
Arm * someArm = new ComplexArm();
// ...
JointVariableVector jvv = someArm.currentJointVariableVector();
ToolConfigurationVector tcv = jvv.toToolConfigurationVector(); // no problem using virtual function
JointVariableVector how = tcv.toJointVariableVector(); // how?
```

I don't want to include any information about which subclass of `Arm` is in use into `ToolConfigurationVector`, the information should be stored somehow in `JointVariableVector`

Of course, I could use templates like this:

```
JointVariableVector<ComplexArm> how = ...
```

But this is not applicable in my case, I have to solve this using **ONLY**

- `someArm`
- `tcv`
- `ToolConfigurationVector`
- `JointVariableVector`

I could of course give `Arm` a virtual method like `jointVariableVectorFromToolConfigurationVector(ToolConfigurationVector v)` but I cannot make it static, and because it has **nothing** to do with the actual `Arm` object implementing it as method (without static) seems wrong to me.

What can I do to get an elegant solution? Of course, this solution should be efficient, too (in terms of needed classes, objects and execution time).

Comment: Sorry for the title, but I can't get this summarized. Could be nominated for a "worst title" award ...

Comment: What about free functions? Are they allowed?

Comment: What exactely do you mean by free functions? I need to convert a `ToolConfigurationVector` to a `JointVariableVector`, but this conversion needs additional information (the **type** of `someArm`). I know how I could do this using a (virtual) method in `Arm`, but this seems wrong to me.

Comment: A free function is a no-member function. An example of free function are std::copy and strcmp.

Comment: Free functions are ok, of course. How would you implement this using a free function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `jvv.toToolConfigurationVector(); // no problem using virtual function` it indicates that `JointVariableVector` holds a pointer or reference to an `Arm` subclass instance, or it is using something like the `pImpl` pattern, in order to engage in behavior virtual in the `Arm` subclass that it was created from.

If you want `ToolConfigurationVector::toJointVariableVector` to create a class which is virtual in what subclass of `Arm` it is specific to, either (A) `ToolConfigurationVector` must be virtual in which subclass of `Arm` the `JointVariableVector` will be virtual in that it produces, or (B) `ToolConfigurationVector::toJointVariableVector` needs to be supplied an `Arm` to create the `JointVariableVector` which will be virtual in the `Arm` subclass.  Ie, pass an `Arm` to `toJointVariableVector`.

Alternatively, the `JointVariableVector` could be some kind of virgin object which later needs to be blessed with `Arm` context before it makes sense, but that makes a mess.

So, to be clear, `JointVariableVector` either has a pointer to an `Arm` (because its representation is a function of said `Arm`), or is a `pImpl` pattern class, based off your syntax (where instances of `JointVariableVector`, and not pointers to same, invoke virtual behavior).  How said `JointVariableVector` is built is a function of the `Arm` it comes from.  The `ToolConfigurationVector` loses that information.  To rebuild a `JointVariableVector` you must then inject the `Arm` back into the situation.

If `JointVariableVector` is only a function of the type of the `Arm` (and not on the instance), then you can make `toJointVariableVector` a template function on the type of `Arm` it is creating a `JointVariableVector` for.  To reduce `ToolConfigurationVector` dependency on `Arm` subclasses, have `ToolConfigurationVector` dispatch the call to a free template function on the type of `Arm`, which you can then implement adjacent to each `Arm` subclass and change the `JointVariableVector` produced.

Which would give you the syntax:

```
Arm * someArm = new ComplexArm();
// ...
JointVariableVector jvv = someArm.currentJointVariableVector();
ToolConfigurationVector tcv = jvv.toToolConfigurationVector();
JointVariableVector how = tcv.toJointVariableVector<ComplexArm>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I have one problem with this: I cannot use `ComplexArm`, I could only use `someArm` which then has to contain runtime type information, as far as I understood. I can't do `tcv.toJointVariableVector<someArm>()`, right?

Comment: Pass the Arm in to the conversion function.  Call a virtual function in Arm that either does the work, or delegates it baxk .